# GUI button issue with bunifu

Tags: vb.net

Im having issues with some GUI in my application (Using bunifu). I made it so that when I click a button, it changes the background color AND the text. I was able to make the background change in the properties but had to make code for the text color, when its activated.

```
Private Sub BunifuFlatButton2_Click_1(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles BunifuFlatButton2.Click
    BunifuFlatButton2.Textcolor = Color.FromArgb(30, 33, 36)
    BunifuFlatButton3.Textcolor = Color.FromArgb(231, 234, 234)
    MEMAPI.WriteByte(MEMAPI.GameStart + OFFSET_UI, 1)
End Sub

Private Sub BunifuFlatButton3_Click_1(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles BunifuFlatButton3.Click
    BunifuFlatButton3.Textcolor = Color.FromArgb(30, 33, 36)
    BunifuFlatButton2.Textcolor = Color.FromArgb(231, 234, 234)
    MEMAPI.WriteByte(MEMAPI.GameStart + OFFSET_UI, 0)
End Sub
```

The issue is when I click another button on the same panel, it forgets that I pressed that button (only visually) and it doesn't stay with the colors I made it to, as you can see with the Gyazo.

https://gyazo.com/e8faba5b59be8416aeaa9e730d955f76

Comment: @KenWhite: Unfortunately, it’s a video.

Comment: Why's that a problem?

Comment: Change the TextColors when you click the other buttons?

Comment: Well, when I click a button, there is a way to make the background color change when its active, but not the text. So I used the code above to fix that. But when I click a button not linked to those 2, It does whats in the gyazo link.

Comment: Also, I would like it to stay activated, even if i hit another button

Answer (score 0):

Clarifications:
Which version of Bunifu Framework are you using, since there were some issues which were fixed on the concurrent updates

Suggestions :
Change Button Forecolor to [White or the TextColor your set on the designer]
Also check OnHoverTextColor [use designer]
Don't forget to check button mismatch could cause UI issue.